# Program keeps crashing when reading from a file using infile and I can't figure out why

Tags: c++

I'm a bit of a newer programming so I apologize if this seems like a stupid question. I'm working on a homework assignment for my data structures class, and am learning about implementing graphs. For the programming assignment, I have to create a graph by reading in a specific file. As part of the assignment, I was already given code for the class graphType that comes directly from the textbook, but I cannot for the life of me implement the createGraph function that came prewritten from the textbook for the assignment. After a lot of debugging by printing out checkpoints every few lines to see where the function stops working, I've found that there seems to be an issue with the infile statements. I am able to successfully open the file, but as soon as the function uses "infile >> temp" in a line, it just stops working and I have no idea why. Here is the code for the createGraph function:

```
void graphType::createGraph()
{
ifstream infile;
char fileName[50];

int index;
int vertex;
int adjacentVertex;

if (gSize != 0) //if the graph is not empty, make it empty
    clearGraph();

cout << "Enter input file name: ";
cin >> fileName;
cout << endl;

infile.open(fileName);

if (!infile)
{
    cout << "Cannot open input file." << endl;
    return;
}

infile >> gSize;  //get the number of vertices

for (index = 0; index < gSize; index++)
{
    infile >> vertex;
    infile >> adjacentVertex;

    while (adjacentVertex != -999)
    {
        graph[vertex].insertLast(adjacentVertex);
        infile >> adjacentVertex;
    } //end while
} // end for

infile.close();
} //end createGraph
```

For reference, gSize is simply an int for the class graphType that is initialized to zero. The information in the textfile that I am attempting to read in is as follows:

```
10
0 1 3 -999
1 4 -999
2 5 -999
3 2 -999
4 -999
5 7 8 -999
6 4 7 -999
7 -999
8 -999
9 7 8 -999
```

Once I reach "infile >> gSize;" it just stops working. Oddly enough, I tried creating a new int size and making it so that the statement was "infile >> size" and that seemed to work, but then I ran into the same issue in the for loop with the vertex and adjecentVertex variables. Any advice is appreciated, so thank you for taking the time to read this!

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I'll go out on a limb: I suspect you haven't allocated/constructed the elements of `graph`, so you're trying to manipulate things that don't exist and getting Undefined Behavior. Can't be certain until you give us a minimal complete example, as @PaulMcKenzie said.

Comment: Not necessarily the problem, but `char fileName[50];` is dangerous. Why not use a `std::string`? You could overrun that array and then poof you are off into undefined behavior.